# Count the records where a field doesn't equal value X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to perform a count on results where a field is not equal to a specific value, but it always fails to returns results.

For instance, assuming **Company** and **Products** have a *one to many relationship*, I might get the following array back from ActiveRecord by querying for `Company.find(63).products` (which would be the SQL equivalent of `SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."company_id" = 63;`):

```
<Product id: 1, company_id: 63, foo_id: 1>,
<Product id: 2, company_id: 63, foo_id: 3>,
<Product id: 3, company_id: 63, foo_id: nil>, 
<Product id: 4, company_id: 63, foo_id: nil>
```

However, if I try to extend the above query to count everything but the first record with the following:

```
Company.find(63).products.where("foo_id != ?", 1).count
```

Which in SQL is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."company_id" = 63 AND (foo_id != 1)
```

I always seem to get **1** back as a result when I expect to see **3**. Why is this happening and how can I get it to count correctly?

Comment: Is `foo_id` on `companies` or `products`?  I'm wondering if you need to combine your `where` clause with the `find` (into a single `where` perhaps), or maybe just move the `where` clause before `products`.

Comment: run this in your mySQL command line....   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."company_id" = 63 AND (foo_id <> 1)

Comment: @JimStewart `foo_id` is actually on products, the child.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with rails and more with the SQL you are trying to execute. Have you tried getting the proper results in a SQL query?

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate Yep, I executed the resulting SQL through psql and I get a count of 0. I'm able to count for the records that are null, however. But sadly that isn't quite what I want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but scratch that 0, I'm actually seeing a result of 1 where I expected to see 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is like you say you should get 1 instead of 0. What you are looking for is `DISTINCT FROM` as `=` and `!=` on null types both return unknown as the result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
products 
WHERE products.company_id = 63 AND (foo_id IS DISTINCT FROM 1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8b7a0/3

And as for further information. `DISTINCT FROM` is PostgreSQL exclusive so the standard version of doing this would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
products
WHERE products.company_id = 63 AND (foo_id<>1 OR foo_id IS NULL)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I think I updated my question result expectations just as you posted your answer. The expected results would in fact be 3 instead of 1 given my example since we're performing the count on the records distinct from the passed value of 1. The SQL you provided still resolves the issue though.

Comment: @Cyle I'm not really sure what you mean. I read your question after your update (I included your query in the fiddle even). Given your sample data you should get 1 as the result since the row with foo_id 3 meets the foo_id!=1 condition. It's visible in the link.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Human error on my part, I'll have to adjust my question to reflect the result of 1 where I have 0. You're question is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `<>` instaed of `!=`

```
<>
```

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work. I also tried the "NOT" operator but no dice.

Comment: is it `NOT`, or is it `IS NOT`?

Comment: I tried `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" WHERE "products"."company_id" = 63 AND (not foo_id = 1)`

Comment: is foo_id a string or integer?

Comment: @drhenner It's an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Company.find(63).products.where("foo_id != ?", 1).count
```

should be

```
Company.find(63).products.where("foo_id <> ?", 1).count
```

but you should take it one step further:

```
class Product
  def self.not_foo(foo_id)
    where("foo_id <> ?", foo_id)
  end
end
```

now

```
 Company.find(63).products.not_foo(1).count
```

Comment: Sadly I tried that already with NewB's solution, produces the same results.